# Homotopy groups relating to toric varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, invariant-theory, geometric-invariant-theory

It is known that the toric variety $X_\Sigma$ of a simplicial fan $\Sigma$ can be constructed as a quotient 
$$X_\Sigma = \bigl(\mathbb C^N \setminus V(B)\bigr)/G.$$
Here $N$ is the number of rays, $B$ is the irrelevant ideal and $G$ is a certain subgroup of the big torus $(\mathbb C^\ast)^N$.

**Assume that $\Sigma$ is a normal fan of a polytope.** Then it is also known that

> (*) $\mathbb C^N \setminus V(B)$ is the complement of the union of sets of (complex) codimension at least $2$.

Questions:

1. **I have heard (at several places) that the fact (*) implies that $\mathbb C^N \setminus V(B)$ is simply connected. How can we prove this?**
2. **Can we see that $\pi_2(\mathbb C^N \setminus V(B))$ vanishes as well?**

Notes:

- We follow the notation in [Cox's lecture notes](http://www3.amherst.edu/~dacox/). (Lectures on toric varieties)
- If $X_\Sigma$ is smooth, we can see that $\pi_2(\mathbb C^N \setminus V(B))=0$: Since $A_{n-1}(X_\Sigma) = H_{2n-2}(X_\Sigma) \cong H^2(X_\Sigma)$ is a free abelian group of rank $b$, $G=\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb Z}(A_{n-1}(X_\Sigma),\mathbb C^*)$ is a complex torus of dimension $b$. The homotopy long exact sequence gives us a short exact sequence of free abelian groups $0\to\pi_2(\mathbb C^N \setminus V(B))\to\pi_2(X_\Sigma)\to\pi_2(BG)\to0$. Since $X_\Sigma$ is $\pi_2(X_\Sigma)$ is also a free abelian group of rank $b$ ($\because$ Hurewicz theorem), the homomorphism $\pi_2(X_\Sigma) \to \pi_2(BG)$ is an isomorphism.
- I am looking for **a direct proof of the 2-connectedness of the Zariski open subset $\mathbb C^N \setminus V(B)$**. Because if we have such a proof, then we can use it to compute some homotopy groups (and cohomology groups) conversely.
- Please do not use glueing construction of toric varieties.

Comment: In the quoted text, I think you mean that $V(B)$ has complex codimension at least $2$ in $\mathbb{C}^N$, right?

Comment: @cws The statement (*) can be found in the paper http://arxiv.org/abs/0708.2710 . I do not know whether $V(B)$ is of codimension at least 2. But if we can see that $\mathbb C^N \setminus X$ is simply connected for a subvariery $X$ of $\mathbb C^N$ of codimension at least 2, then (1) follows from the van Kampen theorem.

Comment: I'm confused; I thought the $V(B)$ was a union of coordinate spaces so that its complement is open in $\mathbb{C}^N$? I posted an answer, which I believe may answer your question given your last comment.

Comment: @cws You are right. The statement which I cited is strange. And thank you for your answer. Let me have some time to think about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X$ is a subvariety of $\mathbb{C}^N$ of complex codimension $\leq 2$, then the fact that $\mathbb{C}^N\smallsetminus X$ is simply connected follows from the normality of $\mathbb{C}^N$ and the Zariski-Nagata purity theorem; see [SGA2 X Theorem 3.4(i)](http://www.math.polytechnique.fr/~laszlo/sga2/sga2-smf.pdf).

You can get both $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ trivial by using general position. See [Lemma 2.4 of this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1403.3307v2.pdf) (full disclosure: I'm the 3rd author) for an argument, which you can apply to the underlying real structure.